# DRM-ing mobi files Amazon's way

Tags: amazon, mobi, drm, azw

I cooperate as a sysadmin with a publishing house. They publish standard
books and ebooks. Ebooks are watermarked. Now they want to add a library
service (lending ebooks for a short time period)

They asked me to investigate the possibility of DRM-ing mobi files
exactly the way Amazon does it (to their proprietary azw format). I know there's a way to remove amazon DRM (I checked it and it works great), so my question is whether it is
possible to "protect" mobi files that way (without Amazon's participation).

Or maybe you know if Amazon has an extra API service for protecting
ebooks (only protecting, without selling)?

I know perfectly well what you think of DRM in general :), I'm
asking because I promised to research the topic .

thx for any hints

Comment: There are numerous MOBI to AZW or AZW*x* converters online and as software; search the net for "MOBI to AZW ". However, you'd best contact Amazon if you plan to use their **proprietary** DRM scheme to publish material. Failure to get their approval could lead to expensive legal complications.